# Change form's action attribute dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form in HTML. Inside the form, there are only two input fields:

`<input type="search">`

`<input type="submit">`

Now, the problem is, how could I change the value of the `action` attribute to the value typed in the `input type='search'`, when I submit the form.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot fathom why anyone would want this, but here's how you do it.

HTML code

```
<form id="searchForm">
  <input type="search" id="search">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

jQuery is

```
<script>
$("#searchForm").on('submit', function(){
  var $userEntered = $(this).children('#search').val();
  $(this).attr("action", $userEntered);
});
</script>
```

This will place whatever the user enters into the search field into the action attribute of the form.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/JohnnyWalkerDesign/bwnvhz24/

(Note: You can see the JSFiddle work by entering something like `https://www.google.com` into the input field. It must begin with `https://` because that's what JSFiddle uses.)

Answer (score 0):

**You can check it .**

HTML code

```
<form action="http://www.google.com" id="checking">
  <button type="submit">click it</button>
</form>
```

script code is

```
<script>
$("#checking").submit(function(e){
  this.action = "http://www.w3schools.com";
});
</script>
```

Comment: No, what I mean is, when the user entered 'www.google.com', then it must go to Google; as well as, if the user entered 'www.w3schools.com', the it must go to the specified site or search.

Comment: whatever site you want `this.action = "http://" + your_site_name  ";` and it will render you there.